# Spark: Is it possible to increase pyarrow buffer?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am attempting to pass a large (~30GB) dataframe to a pandas_udf in spark like so:

```
@f.pandas_udf(gen_udf_schema(), f.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def _my_udf(df):
    # ... do df work ...
    return df

df = df.groupBy('some_col').apply(_my_udf)
```

I tried increasing my executor memory, driver memory, and driver maxResultSize but I am still getting the pyarrow memory error detailed below in my cluster. Is there a equivalent of driver maxResultSize, i.e. `executor maxResultSize` I can use to avoid this error? There does not seem to be much information on this online.

I can't split up the dataframe because it is actually a union of 1 small dataframe, and 1 large dataframe that is ~29GB. Inside my udf I split the two and do my work, and then only return the small dataframe.

```
y4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o324.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 44 in stage 19.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 44.3 in stage 19.0 (TID 368, ip-172-31-13-57.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 3): org.apache.arrow.vector.util.OversizedAllocationException: Unable to expand the buffer
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.BaseVariableWidthVector.reallocBufferHelper(BaseVariableWidthVector.java:547)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.BaseVariableWidthVector.reallocValidityAndOffsetBuffers(BaseVariableWidthVector.java:529)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.BaseVariableWidthVector.handleSafe(BaseVariableWidthVector.java:1221)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.BaseVariableWidthVector.fillEmpties(BaseVariableWidthVector.java:881)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.BaseVariableWidthVector.setSafe(BaseVariableWidthVector.java:1062)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.StringWriter.setValue(ArrowWriter.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowFieldWriter.write(ArrowWriter.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowWriter.write(ArrowWriter.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$2$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply$mcV$sp(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$2$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$2$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:194)
```

Comment: What does your schema look like?  The current java library for Apache Arrow has some limitation for columns (they can't hold more then 2 GB).

Comment: @MicahKornfield apologies for the late reply, I have two string columns that contain "stringified" JSON for ~9,900,000 rows

Comment: I have two string columns that contain "stringified" JSON for ~9,900,000 rows (each is around 490 bytes per row, which leads to ~2.6GB for these columns). I'm going to try to calculate these after the pandas_udf is called to prevent this error